# Russian visa for my Chinese wife

Tags: visas, russia, chinese-citizens

I want to know if my Chinese wife who lives with me in Australia and has a Chinese passport,   and has an Australian partner subclass 820 visa, can obtain a tourist visa for Russia, in Australia or does she have to go back to China to get the Russian visa?

Comment: I can't provide an answer but, if it turns out that nobody has experience with a similar situation on this site, you could ask a Russian consulate in Australia. Those are the people who make and apply the rules in this case (i.e. it's entirely up to Russia to decide where people should apply, there is no general rule).

Answer (score 6):

Information from the page of [Russian Consulate in Sydney](http://www.sydneyrussianconsulate.com/visa.html#q10)

> Dear non-Australian visitors! Please be advised that all non-Australian applicants may apply for visa to the Consulate General of Russia in Sydney only upon presentation of proof of residence in Australia or work/study permit issued by Australian authorities valid for at least 90 days. One of the following documents should be submitted to confirm the same: a valid applicant’s Australian visa in passport, Australian Certificate of citizenship, Australian passport, official document from the Australian Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade, letter from employer specifying the start date of their employment or in case of students, letter from University/College specifying the date of enrolment and course details. Certified copies of the documents or copies with originals should be enclosed to your set of documents, otherwise the application won't be accepted.

So if the subclass 820 visa matches the criteria then she can apply.